# Поясните почему инициализация переменной не проходит?

Tags: java

В первом случае(newList1) код не компилируется, а во втором(newList) все ок.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: СКИДЫВАЙТЕ КОД А НЕ ФОТО!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш первый случай - это поле класса. Поле класса может быть инициализировано четырьмя способами:

1. Значением по умолчанию, в случае любого объектного типа - это `null`

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> newList1;
```

2. Явной инициализацией, например:

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> newList1 = new ArrayList<>();
```

3. В конструкторе, например:

```
public class Main {
    public ArrayList<Integer> newList1;

    public Main() {
        newList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

4. В блоке инициализации, например:

```
public class Main {
    public ArrayList<Integer> newList1;

    {
        newList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Блоки инициализации запускаются друг за другом во время создания объекта, но до запуска конструкторов.

Ваш код больше похож на наименее редко используемый четвёртый способ - инициализация поля класса в блоке инициализации. Вам осталось лишь добавить фигурные скобки.

Comment: Про блок инициализации никогда не слышал. Попробую.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что в первом случае код находится внутри тела класса, где разрешаются декларации и декларации, совмещенные с инициализациями:

```
public ArrayList<String> newList1;
```

или

```
public ArrayList<String> newList1 = new ArrayList<String>();
```

А во втором случае код находится внутри метода, где разрешено то, что Вы написали.

Comment: Так в первом случае тот что в теле класса как раз в 2 этапа декларация/инициализация не проходит, не компилируется.

Comment: @IljaVeselov Прочитайте внимательно то, что я написал в ответе.

Comment: Ок, тогда переформулирую вопрос, почему я не могу в теле класса сначала декларировать переменную а потом дать ей значение как я это делаю в методе Мэйн?

Comment: @IljaVeselov Переформулирую ответ: Потому что в теле класса не разрешается писать выполняемый код (когда он будет выполняться?), если это не инициализация членов класса.

Comment: Вот теперь стало понятнее. Спасибо. А что вы имеете ввиду под членами класса?

Comment: @IljaVeselov Переменные, объявленные в теле класса (не в методе), называются членами (или полями) класса. Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.